# Writing python program to inverse colors of a GIF image, receiving an error

Tags: python, image

I'm currently trying to write a program that reads a GIF file and displays the inverse image on the screen. It is for a class, therefore I cannot download any additional add ons such as PIL. My original code included getting the size of the image and using those dimensions as the width and height, but when I did that I got an error on the line that says "inversePhoto = PhotoImage(width=500, height=250)", which is why I replaced "w" and "h" with the known dimensions of the image, for now. Since then I've received a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alexa/Documents/CS 299/InverseColors.py", line 31, in <module>
    r,g,b = getRGB(photo, x, y)
  File "C:/Users/Alexa/Documents/CS 299/InverseColors.py", line 13, in getRGB
    value = photo.get(x, y)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3438, in get
    return self.tk.call(self.name, 'get', x, y)
_tkinter.TclError: pyimage1 get: coordinates out of range
```

I'm not quite sure what this error means...I'm assuming it has something to do x and y being either too small or too large for the image, but I'm not sure how that could be...here is my full code, I appreciate any help that can guide me in the right direction.

```
# InverseColors.py

# This program is designed to read a GIF file and display the inverse(negative) of its image

from tkinter import *
import struct

root = Tk()

def getRGB(photo, x, y):
    value = photo.get(x, y)
    return tuple(map(int, value.split(" ")))
def getImageSize(fileName):
    handle = open(fileName, 'rb')
    head = handle.read(24)
    if len(head) != 24:
        return
    width, height = struct.unpack('>ii', head[16:24])
    return width, height
def inverse(image, r, g, b, x, y):
    image.put("#%02x%02x%02x" % ((255-r),(255-g),(255-b)), (y,x))

w, h = getImageSize("picture.gif")
photo = PhotoImage(file="picture.gif")
inversePhoto = PhotoImage(width=500, height=250)

for x in range(0,500):
    for y in range(0,250):
        r,g,b = getRGB(photo, x, y)
        inverse(inversePhoto, r, g, b, x, y)

label = Label(root, image=inversePhoto)
label.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I dont get any errors when I run it and it looks inversed...can you post a link to the gif?

Comment: That's strange...I ran the program on a different computer, and it ran with no errors.. however, it only showed half of the inverted image, and it turned it on its side. Not sure why it did that.

Comment: I saw the same thing on my end

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the error - I had x and y mixed up on one of the lines (in the inverse function)